# Textmate default preferences

Tags: textmate

In trying to get Textmate 2.0-alpha.9495 to show Hidden files I managed to screw it up so that the project view only shows folders, no files.

1. How can I reset it to the default settings?
   or
2. What should the default setting for "Exclude Files Matching" be?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reset to default settings**

According to the Github project wiki (https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Reverting-To-Defaults), the following files/folders have to be removed:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Avian
~/Library/Application Support/TextMate
~/Library/Caches/com.macromates.TextMate/BundlesIndex.binary
~/Library/Caches/com.macromates.TextMate/BundlesIndex.plist (v2.0-alpha.9465 and earlier)
~/Library/Preferences/com.macromates.textmate.plist
~/.tm_properties
```

This resets everything, any bundle customizations will be lost too. I would recommend to check any .tm_properties files first - the one in your home directory AND the one in your project directory.

**Default setting for "Exclude Files Matching"**

That would be:

```
exclude  = "{*.{o,pyc},Icon\r,CVS,_darcs,_MTN,\{arch\},blib,*~.nib}"
```

You can look up all default settings in this file:

```
TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/Default.tmProperties
```

Comment: Thanks. Your exclude string is what I needed.