# TextMate won't find files in project folder

Tags: textmate, textmate2

This was working before, but now whenever I use TextMate to find matches across all files in my project folder, it says searched 0 files.

Has anyone had this happen to them and what did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this has happened to me. I've been able to fix it in an number of ways.

Starting from the beginning;

`[Edit -> Find -> Find in Project]` or `[Command + Shift + F]` is how you open the Find window with your project preselected.

This should produce a window similar to this;

[image: Find in project window with project below]

Some important fields;

- "In: " is set to your project folder.
- "Regular Expression" is unchecked.
- "Matching" is set to *. This will search every file

Any of these could cause unexpectedly empty searches.

However, this is pretty much day to day stuff, so once you've checked this there's a few more things to look at.

TextMate will look in a few places for Find Window includes and excludes, so check in `~/.tm_properties` and `[Your Project]/.tm_properties` for these excludes;

- exclude
- excludeFiles
- excludeDirectories
- excludeInBrowser
- excludeInFolderSearch
- excludeInFileChooser
- excludeFilesInBrowser
- excludeDirectoriesInBrowser

From dvessel's [tm_properties documentation](https://gist.github.com/dvessel/1478685#file-filters)

> These are all globs and perhaps a bit arcane. (Note that the glob syntax is documented in the built-in help system.)
>
> The file browser, if it has a file, checks that file against the first key with a value in this order: excludeFilesInBrowser, excludeInBrowser, excludeFiles, exclude. If neither match, it then does the same with include keys, and if one match, it is included.
>
> The default include key is * (so no hidden files, although see the default .tm_properties which include .htaccess and .tm_properties). The default exclude key is the empty string (nothing matches).

The defaults for `.tm_properties` files are located here: TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/Default.tmProperties

If worse comes to worse, you can reset TextMate to its defaults following this [Stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846448/textmate-default-preferences)